# Creating a folder in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and have read lots of tutorials, tried bunches of code but still can't understand how 
to create a folder in internal storage.

I need to create a folder in which I wil put a json resource file.

Manifest file contains  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

My code sample is:

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val folder = File(
            Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + separator.toString() + "MetroPol"
        )
        if (folder.exists()) {
            d("folder", "exists")
        } else {
            d("folder", "not exists")
            folder.mkdirs()
        }
    }
```

I test it using my phone connected to a pc and recognised by Android Studio. When this app launches I go to a browser and don't see any new folder.

What should be done here?

Comment: `if ( !   folder.mkdirs()) Toast(could not make folder) else Toast(folder created). ` Check the return value of mkdir()!

Comment: `I go to a browser and don't see any new folder.` Browser? Or a file manager app? Other apps have no acces to your apps private data directory. No wonder you see nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a folder inside your Internal Storage, try out this code snippet

```
val folder = filesDir
val f = File(folder, "folder_name")
f.mkdir()
```

Finally to check if the folder is created open Device Explorer in Android Studio, then follow the path

**data->data->your app package name -> files->** here should be your folder that you created programmatically. Hope this helps

Comment: It truly helps however I checked t by `exists()` method. But still I cannot found it on my phone. Can it be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to Kotlin and have read lots of tutorials, tried bunches of code but still can't understand how to create a folder in internal storage.

It seems as though you really want to be creating a directory in [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Since that is no longer being supported on Android 10 (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps), I recommend that you let the user create the directory themselves, and you get access to it via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and the Storage Access Framework.

> When this app launches I go to a browser and don't see any new folder.

The root of external storage is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: just read from another answers about external storage, thought that it's necesarry to put `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifest in any cases. Actually I need to perform it in internal storage: create a folder and put files there.

Comment: @PavelPereverzev: "thought that it's necesarry to put WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest in any cases" -- oh, you need that too, and to request the permission at runtime. I was focusing on the bugs in what you posted. "Actually I need to perform it in internal storage" -- you are welcome to use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), such as `getFilesDir()` on `Context`. That works much better, as you do not need any permissions and it works normally on Android 10+. However, the user has no access to those files.

Comment: I wanted to test it in `MainActivity`. As far as I understood `context` has to be declared in input values?

Comment: @PavelPereverzev: I do not know what you mean by that. Most likely `MainActivity` *is* a `Context`, unless you have an unusual naming convention. Details on how to perform disk I/O in Android are covered in many books and courses on Android app development.

Answer (score 0):

```
val appDirctory =File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/test")
appDirctory.mkdirs()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also try this

```
val relativeLocationPictures =
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + "GPS camera app" + File.separator + "Pictures" + File.separator + folderName
                val folder = File(relativeLocationPictures)
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    if (folder.mkdirs()) {
                        // Folder created successfully
                    } else {
                        // Failed to create the folder
                    }
                } else {
                    // Folder already exists
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this ?

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var filename = "test.txt"
        val folder = File("/sdcard/MetroPol/")
        folder.mkdirs()
        val outputFile = File(folder, filename)
        try {
            val fos = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Comment: still nothing happens :(

Comment: What if a device doesn't have /sdcard ? Why not use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`?